# Select without making a duplicate

Tags: mysql

For the sake of brevity lets say I have a table which looks like this:

```
item_name    item_location    item_price
PROMO_A      local            5
B            local            7
PROMO_A      global           8
```

Now, what I am doing is I'm selecting all records where item_location is 'local' or where the the `item_name` contains word `PROMO` but the `item_location` is not 'local'. This, in my SQL query looks straightforward:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE item_location='local' OR (item_name like 'PROMO%' AND item_location != 'local');
```

Now, it could happen, as in the example data I've set up above that I would get two identical `item_name`'s so I'm wondering how could I fix this query so that the latter one wouldn't be added? I can fix this by writing a PHP program which would go through the records and remove the duplicates (I need to remove the duplicates (the ones with same item_name) which have item_location=='global') but I was wondering if this could be done using just SQL? I was thinking of making a temporary table of the above query and then query for distinct item_name records, but how would then I in that case remove the ones with item_location 'global'?

Anyways, any help is appreciated.

edit: I've set up a [SQL Fiddle link for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2490c/1).

edit2: I managed to get this working with the following query:

> SELECT * FROM mytable
>   WHERE item_location = 'local'
>
> UNION
>
> SELECT * FROM mytable
>   WHERE item_name LIKE 'PROMO%' AND item_name NOT IN
>   (SELECT item_name from mytable WHERE item_location = 'local' )

And the sql fiddle link for this is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49800/2).

Now, I believe this could be handled in a better way so if someone has better approaches, I would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT on or fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UNION` query may be simplified to

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE item_location = 'local'
OR item_name LIKE 'PROMO%' AND item_name NOT IN
   (SELECT item_name FROM mytable
    WHERE item_location = 'local' )
```

Another query that gives the same result using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery is

```
SELECT mt.* FROM mytable AS mt
LEFT JOIN mytable as mt2
ON mt2.item_name = mt.item_name      -- check for similar items
AND mt2.item_location = 'local'      -- whose location is 'local'
WHERE mt.item_location = 'local'
OR mt.item_name LIKE 'PROMO%'
AND mt2.item_location IS NULL;       -- only include if not found locally
```

Comment: Thx, this query works and would you see it's 'better' in terms of speed? As the one I made seems easier to comprehend. Is using UNION not suggested because of performace or some other issues?

Comment: I have now added a simplified version of you `UNION` query, which probably is more efficient than the original, but can't say how it will compare to the query using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the subquery.  If performance is a problem, you should test both queries.